# How to search with a regex for →

Tags: node.js, regex

i have a → in the String. (nodejs) \t is not working. What is the name of → and how could i regex it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape this character like this: `\u2192`.

Answer (score 2):

It's called the ["Rightwards Arrow"](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2192), U+2192. But since this is a plain unicode character, you can put it into a pattern *just by putting it into the pattern* as a literal character, nothing special needed:

```js
const pattern = /→\w+/g;
console.log('→foo→bar'.match(pattern));
```